# Google Map Api Feature Layer click event not getting fired when clicking on Map POI

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, event-handling

My code follows like this:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            fullscreenControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            clickableIcons:false,
            mapId:<My Map Id>
});
```

```
featureLayer.addListener('click', function(event) {
  /* when clickableIcons is false,
       1. on click of feature layer it will fire this event and map click event will not fire. 
       2. "on click of POI elements that are on feature layer, **this event will not fire but map click event will fires**" 

     when clickableIcons is true,
       1. on click of feature layer it will fire this event and map click event will not fire.
       2. "on click of POI elements that are on feature, **first this event will fire than map click event will fire**"
*/
});
```

```
map.addListener('click', function(event) {
  /* map click event*/
});
```

Now the problem is that on click of Map landmark/POI elements it by default opens popup which I don't want,
so I made `clickableIcons` as false which solved this problem of popup.

But, now when I click the POI elements that are on `featureLayer` I cannot trigger the `featureLayer` click event it only fires map click event which I don't need.

**What I want to know if there is any way to fire `featureLayer` event by disabling the popup that comes on click of landmark/POI.**

What I tried is,
I made `clickableIcons:fals`e since now it will not fire the `featureLayer` click event if I click on POI elements,
I tried to check if I can get `placeId` from map click event but no luck in that.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to attach event listeners directly to the map container and then determine the coordinates of the click event. You can then perform custom logic to determine if the click falls within the vicinity of a landmark/POI, and handle the event accordingly.

Comment: can you give me some sort of code snippet to check weather click falls on that feature layer? using lat long.
i mean we can get lat long from click but how to check if that is inside the particular feature layer